# Spanish Language Text In Url

Tags: multilingual

I have a client who would like to use spanish language urls.  In other words they would like to have www.mydomain.com/los-miembros for the spanish version of www.mydomain.com/members.

Anyone have guidance as to how to accomplish this?

Sitecore 8.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `useDisplayName` attribute on your Link Provider to true.  Then you can translate the display names for you items.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager>
      <providers>
        <add name="sitecore" set:useDisplayName="true"/>
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This was also answered on SO by jammykam: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941965/2911685

Comment: Ack, thanks Ben.  Solid googling, mine needs work!